# angular2-material md-content scrolling issue

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to make a structure where,

1. `md-toolbar` is always fixed
2. Only `md-content` scrolls on whole page if content is overflowing.
3. `md-sidenav` along with its content should be fixed always irrespective of    its mode ('over' or 'side')

Image for reference :-
[image]

After trying and wasting time for 2 days now, I was able to achieve the structure in the plunkr below.It scrolls the whole page and not only the content.

```
[PLUNKR DEMO][2]
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/ORA0KloDddgseMIOQ71i?p=preview

Structure I am trying to use :-

```
<md-sidenav-layout>
    <md-sidenav #start mode="{{hasMedia('gt-xs') ? 'side' : 'over'}}" [opened]="true">


    </md-sidenav>

    <md-content flex >
        <md-toolbar class="fixed-toolbar" color="warn">


        </md-toolbar>
        <div layout="column" layout-fill layout-align="top center">

            <div class="routerview">
                <router-outlet></router-outlet> // the only dynamically changing part in whole SPA.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div flex></div>
    </md-content>
</md-sidenav-layout>
```

Comment: plunker does not seem to work as mentioned

Comment: I will try changing link. I dont why but it seems that link is working only from my account. If you saying its stucked at angular 2 is loading then it actually slow. it takes time to load

Answer (score 0):

Md-content is not yet implemented in angular2 material, it is not clear if or when they will implement it.